# Google script to edit a time trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to edit the timing of a trigger based on a value in a cell of a spreadsheet. The only way I can think of is to set a trigger for a function that is deleting all triggers and making new triggers based on the value of a cell. Is there a way to edit the existing timing of existing triggers?

Comment: Be more specific or checkout [this Link for yourself](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app).

Answer (score 0):

You can delete just one.

```
function deleteTrigger(funcName)
{
  var triggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for(var i=0;i<triggers.length;i++)
  {
    if(funcName==triggers[i].getHandlerFunction())
    {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
      break;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I run things at variable time intervals by setting my trigger to the minimum interval I need, tying the trigger to a function that tests against criteria.  If criteria is met, I execute the desired function.  You could implement this principle where the criteria for whether to execute the main function is dependent on the cell contents (or direct it to different functions depending on the contents of the cell).